# R dict and list

Tags: r

can you tell me how to create a data structure as in the example below in R ?

```
my_list <- list(list())
my_list[21]["A"] = 7
my_list[21]["B"] = 1
my_list[34]["A"] = 12
my_list[34]["B"] = 1
my_list[78]["A"] = 11
my_list[78]["B"] = 2
my_list[298]["A"] = 11
my_list[298]["B"] = 1
```

thank you very much

Comment: What is the application you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to Python IMO in R this would be a matrix (or a dataframe if the values are not all of the same type). I've limited the number of rows/a smaller example:

```
MyROWS <- 5

m <- matrix(rep(NA, (2 * MyROWS)), ncol = 2)
colnames(m) <- c("A", "B")

m[2, "A"] <- 7
m[2, "B"] <- 1
# etc
m

#A  B
#[1,] NA NA
#[2,]  7  1
#[3,] NA NA
#[4,] NA NA
#[5,] NA NA
```